The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within... GOOGLE CLOUD GCP
I am trying to upload my express with typescript project to Cloud Run on GCP, via Artifact Registry with a docker container. My app connects to an instance of Cloud Sql.
I am getting this error:

Revision is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided
container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by
the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This
can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout
is too short.

I have some .env variables:
PORT=8080

# GOOGLE CLOUD SQL
POSTGRES_URL=postgresql://postgres:xxxxxx@34.69.171.xxx:5432/aero-node
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=aero-node
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

This is my Dockerignore:
node_modules

.env

*.log

.DS_Store
Thumbs.db

.git
.gitignore

dist/
build/

.dockerignore
Dockerfile

npm-debug.log
yarn-debug.log
yarn-error.log

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:22-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl libssl-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

This is my app.ts:
port: envs.PORT || 8080,

I run locally my docker image and works perfectly:
This is my Cloud Run secrets configuration:

I've been trying everything but nothing seems to works.

Please update your question to include the logs. The error message "failed to start and listen on port 8080" is correct but it can be misunderstood. It generally means "the container failed to start" and so seeing the logs will be helpful. It can be confusing because it's often misinterpreted by developers as "didn't start on port 8080" and that becomes the developer's focus.

Likely nothing wrong with port configuration. I hate this error message "failed to start and listen on port 8080" from Cloud Run because it makes it appear that port configuration is wrong. If your container comes up fine locally, your best bet is to investigate Cloud Run logs.
